# npm scripts command won't run

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify

I have this in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "browserify app/components/main.js -o build/js/app.js -d"
}
```

When I run this command from shell, it executes and creates the file just fine.
But when I run `npm build`, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're running into a problem because `npm build` is a command in npm itself. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/build

Try doing `npm run-script build` or `npm run build` to explicitly run the script named build.

See also: [`npm build` doesn't run my build scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939697/npm-build-doesnt-run-my-build-scripts)