# Problems building 1.0 beta

Tags: quill

I am encountering the following errors trying to run `npm start`. It looks like there is a "build" script in package.json. `npm build` outputs nothing. Any ideas?

```
λ npm start                                                                                                    

> quill@1.0.0-beta.1 start C:\repos\github\quill                                                               
> npm run build; foreman start -f _develop/procfile                                                            

npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.                                                
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586                                                                                 
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli
.js" "run" "build;" "foreman" "start" "-f" "_develop/procfile"                                                 
npm ERR! node v4.2.1                                                                                           
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7                                                                                          

npm ERR! missing script: build;                                                                                
npm ERR!                                                                                                       
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:                                                       
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>                                                               

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:                                           
npm ERR!     C:\repos\github\quill\npm-debug.log                                                               

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586                                                                                 
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli
.js" "start"                                                                                                   
npm ERR! node v4.2.1                                                                                           
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7                                                                                          
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                                                       
npm ERR! quill@1.0.0-beta.1 start: `npm run build; foreman start -f _develop/procfile`                         
npm ERR! Exit status 1                                                                                         
npm ERR!                                                                                                       
npm ERR! Failed at the quill@1.0.0-beta.1 start script 'npm run build; foreman start -f _develop/procfile'.    
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the quill package,                                                 
npm ERR! not with npm itself.                                                                                  
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:                                                       
npm ERR!     npm run build; foreman start -f _develop/procfile                                                 
npm ERR! You can get their info via:                                                                           
npm ERR!     npm owner ls quill                                                                                
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.                                                      

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:                                           
npm ERR!     C:\repos\github\quill\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

[npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) are run with `npm run` so you would need to call `npm run build`. Why `npm build` does nothing is a npm quirk: [`npm build` doesn't run the script named "build" in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939697/npm-build-doesnt-run-my-build-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

change start sript to this:

```
"start": "npm run build \"foreman start -f _develop/procfile\"",
```

A few characters are escaped