# Webpack build step isn't generating build files

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

When I run `npm build` nothing seems to happen. When I look for the build files I don't see anything. `npm start` works fine though.

#### Package.json

```
{
  "name": "pro-react-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./webpack.production.config.js --progress",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.9.1",
    "precss": "^1.4.0",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.1"
  }
}
```

#### Webpack.production.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + "/app/main.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/build",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: "json"
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?modules!postcss')
            }
        ]
    },
    postcss: [
        require('autoprefixer')
    ],

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: __dirname + "/app/index.tmpl.html"
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css")
    ]
}
```

I also have .babelrc file and webpack.config.js file, let me know if those would be useful to see as well, thanks.

Comment: It should be `npm run build`. [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be related to the fact that build is an internal command. Seems like I have had this happen to me as well in the past. Check out this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939697/npm-build-doesnt-run-the-script-named-build-in-package-json)

In order to run a custom script, you can use the `npm run-script build` or just `npm run build`. As stated in the [NPM documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script)