# npm run build doesn't seem to work

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I am running `npm run build` on terminal but the script isn't executing. It just runs but doesn't do anything.

Attaching my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-starter",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts":{
      "build":"tsc --rootDir src --outDir dist"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.7",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.7.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^2.1.5",
    "typings": "^2.1.0"
  }
}
```

This is what I am getting on running:

```
$ npm run build

> angular2-starter@0.1.0 build C:\Users\user\desktop\angular2-starter
> tsc --rootDir src --outDir dist
```

Tried checking [`npm build` doesn't run the script named "build" in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939697/npm-build-doesnt-run-the-script-named-build-in-package-json) but couldn't resolve the error.

Please tell me what wrong am I doing here.

Comment: it IS running the script, as shown by `> tsc --rootDir src --outDir dist`. so npm and package.json are unrelated

Comment: `unrelated` what does this mean?

Comment: It means not related. Not part of the problem. Your problem is with `tsc`

Comment: Alright. Can you guide me to some source where I can seek answers?

Comment: No, i'm unfamiliar with tsc.

Comment: thanx anyways..

Comment: I don't think the problem is with `tsc` because when I run the command from `node_modules/.bin` it does create a `dist` folder in the project. So it has something to do with the `build` or the command I guess. @KevinB