# What is the difference between npm install and npm run build?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

What is the difference between `npm install` and `npm run build`?

I have noticed in my project that sometimes npm starts failing when `npm install` is performed, but, upon running `npm run build`, it works just fine.

How do the inner workings of these two targets namely `install` and `run build` differ?

Comment: The accepted answer as of now is debatable. I think the answers from MKP and CTS_AE, are more relevant at this given time. With due respect, This should come under the notice of moderator &/or the one who asked this question.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

`npm install` installs dependencies into the `node_modules/` directory, for the node project you're working on. You can call `install` on another node.js project (module), to install it as a dependency for your project.

`npm run build` does nothing unless you specify what "build" does in your package.json file. It lets you perform any necessary building/prep tasks for your project, prior to it being used in another project.

`npm build` is an internal command and is called by `link` and `install` commands, according to [the documentation for build](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-build):

> This is the plumbing command called by npm link and npm install.

You will not be calling `npm build` normally as it is used internally to build native C/C++ Node addons using node-gyp.

Comment: After referring the below link's correct answer, I also think that `npm build` and `npm run build` are not the same. IMHO, Maybe the above answer from @churro needs to be corrected. Please correct me if I am wrong.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939697/npm-build-doesnt-run-the-script-named-build-in-package-json?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: So npm install automatically runs npm run build for all the dependencies scripts? Where is that documented?

Answer (score 152):

## NPM in 2019

`npm build` no longer exists. You must call `npm run build` now. More info below.

### TLDR;

**`npm install`**: installs dependencies, then calls the `install` from the `package.json` `scripts` field.

**`npm run build`**: runs the build field from the `package.json` `scripts` field.

---

### NPM Scripts Field

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

There are many things you can put into the npm `package.json` scripts field. Check out the documentation link above more above the lifecycle of the scripts - most have pre and post hooks that you can run scripts before/after install, publish, uninstall, test, start, stop, shrinkwrap, version.

---

### To Complicate Things

- `npm install` is not the same as `npm run install`
- `npm install` installs `package.json` dependencies, then runs the `package.json` `scripts.install`

  - (Essentially calls `npm run install` after dependencies are installed.
- `npm run install` only runs the `package.json` `scripts.install`, it **will not install dependencies**.
- `npm build` used to be a valid command (used to be the same as `npm run build`) but it no longer is; it is now an internal command. If you run it you'll get: `npm WARN build npm build called with no arguments. Did you mean to npm run-script build?` You can read more on the documentation: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/build or https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-build

---

### Extra Notes

There are still two top level commands that will run scripts, they are:

- `npm start` which is the same as `npm run start`
- `npm test` ==> `npm run test`

Comment: +1 But it's confusing to say `npm build` doesn't exist anymore. It still exsits in the sense that it's known/special to npm, because it reacts with the warning you mention in the bottom. Essentially it does nothing now. [This answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29939697/1804173) gave the shortest summary on `npm build` vs `npm run build`.

Comment: I just tried using yarn on a recent project promoted by none other than the folks at Salesforce.. yarn did not work. But NPM worked beautifully

Comment: Link is broken, here's an updated one: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-build

Comment: So `npm install` automatically runs `npm run build` for all the dependencies scripts? Where is that documented?

Answer (score 60):

The main difference is:

> *`npm install` is a npm CLI-command which does the predefined thing i.e., as written by Churro, to install dependencies specified inside `package.json`*.

> *`npm run %command-name%` or `npm run-script %command-name%` is also a CLI-command predefined to run your custom scripts with the name specified in place of "command-name". So, in this case `npm run build` is a custom script command with the name "build" and will do anything specified inside it (for instance `echo 'hello world'` given in below example `package.json`).*

Points to note::

1. One more thing, `npm build` and `npm run build` are two different things, `npm run build` will do **custom work** written inside `package.json` and `npm build` is a **pre-defined** script (not available to use directly).
2. You cannot specify some thing inside custom build script (`npm run build`) script and expect `npm build` to do the same. Try following thing to verify in your `package.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "demo",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "echo 'hello build'"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {},
    "dependencies": {}
}
```

and run `npm run build` and `npm build` one by one and you will see the difference. For more about commands kindly follow [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/npm).

Comment: Rather than "try to run this", I'd appreciate if you explain in more detail what is the difference between `npm run build` and `npm build`. Ok so they're not the same, in what way ? So @Churro's answer is incorrect then ?

Comment: Yeah, what `npm build` does remains a mystery. Would be nice to know that.
As far as I can tell, _"`npm build` will do as written by Churro"_ is not true. Churro said it would do what's specified in `package.json` for the `build` command (as defined in the `scripts` section I suppose). But that's what `npm run build` does, and `npm build` does not run the build command specified in `package.json` `scripts` section. Unless there is some other way to define what `npm build` should do in the `package.json`, which is not explained here, nor by Churro (nor in the NPM docs, I think, sadly).

Comment: So I tried it and `npm build` said _npm WARN build `npm build` called with no arguments. Did you mean to `npm run-script build`?_. I think it did nothing. After spending time to read all answers here and trying this myself I still cannot tell what's the purpose of `npm build` :(.

Answer (score 7):

- `npm install` installs the depedendencies in your package.json config.
- `npm run build` runs the script "build" and created a script which runs your application - let's say server.js
- `npm start` runs the "start" script which will then be "node server.js"

It's difficult to tell exactly what the issue was but basically if you look at your scripts configuration, I would guess that "build" uses some kind of build tool to create your application while "start" assumes the build has been done but then fails if the file is not there.

You are probably using bower or grunt - I seem to remember that a typical grunt application will have defined those scripts as well as a "clean" script to delete the last build.

Build tools tend to create a file in a bin/, dist/, or build/ folder which the start script then calls - e.g. "node build/server.js". When your `npm start` fails, it is probably because you called `npm clean` or similar to delete the latest build so your application file is not present causing npm start to fail.

npm build's source code - to touch on the discussion in this question - is in github for you to have a look at if you like. If you run `npm build` directly and you have a "build" script defined, it will exit with an error asking you to call your build script as `npm run-script build` so it's not the same as `npm run script`.

I'm not quite sure what `npm build` does, but it seems to be related to postinstall and packaging scripts in dependencies. I assume that this might be making sure that any CLI build scripts's or native libraries required by dependencies are built for the specific environment after downloading the package. This will be why link and install call this script.