# What is difference between "npm build", "npm run build", "npm install" and "npm run install"

Tags: npm

What is the difference between `npm build` vs, `npm run build` and `npm install` vs `npm run install`?

Comment: `npm build` is an alias for `npm run build`
`npm install` is an alias for `npm run install`

See docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between npm install and npm run build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664200/what-is-the-difference-between-npm-install-and-npm-run-build)