# What is npm run build command and how webpack is used in creating bundle file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, server, client

### What's the difference between npm run build and npm install webpack?

In what ways these commands differ

Comment: npm run build executes the script 'build' in package.json. npm install webpack installs the package 'webpack' in your project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between npm install and npm run build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664200/what-is-the-difference-between-npm-install-and-npm-run-build)

Comment: webpack tool ---> npm run build (command in package.json) -----> create bundles. So is this order correct?

Comment: @Little_Programmer the correct order is npm run build (command in package.json) --> which runs webpack script (webpack tool) --> and then webpack reads the configurations(if any) and creates bundles.

Comment: https://medium.com/javascript-training/beginner-s-guide-to-webpack-b1f1a3638460

Answer (score 1):

[webpack](https://survivejs.com/webpack/what-is-webpack/) is a module bundler for javascript application. In order to run webpack ypu need to get the webapck in your project.`npm install webpack` will install webpack from node module software library using `npm install webpack` command.

`npm run build` is a separate command to build the code. If you open `package.json` inside `scripts` you may see a key like `build` example

```
scripts:{
 build:someValue
}
```

Comment: ok, if I have not declared "npm run build" in package.json then nothing will happen. Scripts in package.json what value should I give to make the "npm run build" work. My question is are we pointing the Webpack tool in the package.json to execute the "npm run build". ?

Comment: Then can we define a webpack as build tool?