# Devops npm task with custom command (build) not working

Tags: npm, build, azure-devops, npm-install

I am trying to automate the build process (Azure Devops) for my Vue.js application by making use of "npm" task.

To Install the node packages, I have used npm task with built in "install" command.

For build process, I have deployed another npm task but with custom command (build). This custom build command runs successfully with the following warning

> "npm WARN build 'npm build' called with no arguments. Did you mean to
>   'npm run-script build'?"

I believe it is not doing the build at all as when I go the Copy Publish Artifact, it says

> Total files copied: 0. [warning]Directory 'D:\a\3\a\drop' is empty.
>   Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.

I have tried 'npm run-script build' command but get the error

> "NPM failed with return code: 1"

There are some stack overflow threads ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939697/npm-build-doesnt-run-the-script-named-build-in-package-json)) where people mentioned the build as an internal command of install. If that's really the case, why I can't see the dist folder created by the install command or I am doing something wrong with my custom command npm task?

[image]

NPM Install Task
[image]

NPM Install Task with custom Build Command
[image]

npm install Task log
[image]

npm build Task log
[image]

Copy and Publish Artifact Task
[image]

Copy and Publish Task log
[image]

The script section in package.json file

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For "npm build" task, the custom command (In question above, tried "build" and "npm run-script build") should be "run-script build". The build has successfully created the dist folder.

[image]