# Npm Run Script Issues Running ( Blank Line After Running & No Errors)

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I logged into my codebase and tried to run a script. onEnter it doesn't run or give any errors but shows a blank line beneath. everything was working fine until I restarted it. The only things I've edited have been in a Vue file which shouldn't affect anything?
( image below )

Ive tried:
- installing npm and I've looked [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939697/npm-build-doesnt-run-the-script-named-build-in-package-json) on a similar issue. 
- updating and it has updated, the test command gives the same result. 
- reinstalling node and the issue persists. 
- running the commands in different terminal

[image]

Comment: could you provide more information, how did you install npm?

You shouldn't have to call node from the modules like that

You should be able to set up a script like this:
with src being a folder and index.js being the main script file


node src/index.js

Comment: So everything was working fine until i restarted and ran it again. nothing changed in the package.json other than an update to es-abstract. and the only thing Ive been doing has been inside a vue file. I run `npm i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few days ago watching a Coding Tech video they recommended running `npm config set ignore-scripts true` to prevent hackers when installing npm libraries etc. However... this prevents you from running ANYTHING. 
 run `npm config set ignore-scripts false` and it should be fixed. DAMN.

Comment: Pretty curious why that is the case, the dude was rambling on about there is a potential malicious virus spread due to possibility of executing random scripts that come with the package right?