# How to fix missing script "build" when running npm run build?

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I am trying to deploy on Netlify and when I run npm run build I get missing script error.
I see that I already have build script in my package.json. [package.json image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb3Qk.png)

How can I fix this?

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs0Nm.png)

Comment: can you add the error here ?

Comment: just added a screenshot of the error

Answer (score 0):

Change the script name from build to something else (build is reserved) like build-dev

check this out: [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939697/npm-build-doesnt-run-the-script-named-build-in-package-json)

Comment: Changed script name from build to build-dev but still getting same error.

Comment: you use npm run build-dev ?